Python code to trim HTML content without losing html structure
post trimming of HTML content as the remaining tags are trimmed/not closed properly, HTML structure breaks and the code is rendered with tags visible as:
< body> < able> [if mso]> < d> <![endif] [if mso]> < r> < able> <![endif] < d> < r> < body> < able>
Viac na Právne noviny < d> < r> < body> < able> < d> < r> < body> < able>
...[trimmed]
def trim_html(html: str) -> str:
    max_length = 70000

    if len(html) < max_length:
        return html
    html = html.replace('/n', '').replace('/t', ' ').replace('/r', '')

    notice = "...[trimmed]"
    current_length = 0
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    output_soup = BeautifulSoup('', 'html.parser')

    for element in soup.descendants:
        if element.name is None:
            available_length = max_length - current_length - len(notice)
            if available_length <= 0:
                break
            text_to_add = element[:available_length]
            current_length += len(text_to_add)
            output_soup.append(text_to_add)
            if len(text_to_add) < len(element):
                break
        else:
            new_tag = output_soup.new_tag(element.name, attrs=element.attrs)
            output_soup.append(new_tag)
    output_soup.append(notice)
    return str(output_soup)


from html.parser import HTMLParser
import logging
import re


"""
Purpose: 
    trim_parse_html : function is to trim HTML content while retaining the original HTML structure.
"""

_TRIMMED_TXT: str = ' </pre> <span style="color:red;font-weight:bold">[DATA TRIMMED ...]</span>'
_TRIMMED_HTM: str = '<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold">[DATA TRIMMED ...]</span>'
_WARNING_TXT: str = '<h3 style="color: red;"> &#9888; WARNING! INCOMPLETE FEED TEXT REF. SOURCE.</h3>\n <pre> '
_WARNING_HTM: str = '<h3 style="color: red;"> &#9888; WARNING! INCOMPLETE FEED DATA REF. SOURCE.</h3>\n'
_NO_TRIMMING: str = '' # '<h3 style="color: red;"> NO TRIMMING </h3>\n '
_SKIP_TAGS : str = ['script', 'style']

class TrimParser(HTMLParser):
    __limit_reached: bool = False
    __parse_len = 0

    __tags = []
    __tags_stack = []
    __warning_added: bool = False

    def __init__(self, max_len=70000):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.margin = min(max(max_len * 5 / 100, 100), max_len * 50 / 100)
        self.max_len = max_len - self.margin

    def __push_tag(self, tag):
        self.__tags_stack.append(tag)

    def __peek_tag(self):
        if self.__tags_stack:
            return self.__tags_stack[-1]
        else:
            return None

    def __pop_tag(self):
        if not self.__isempty_stack():
            return self.__tags_stack.pop()

    def __isempty_stack(self) -> object:
        return len(self.__tags_stack) == 0

    def __closing_html(self):
        closing_tags = []
        while not self.__isempty_stack():
            closing_tags.append(f'</{self.__pop_tag()}>\r')
        return ''.join(closing_tags)

    def html_text(self):
        return ''.join(self.__tags).strip() + self.__closing_html().strip()

    def handle_startendtag(self, tag, attrs):
        self.__tags.append(f'<{tag}/>')

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if not self.__limit_reached:
            self.__push_tag(tag)
            self.__tags.append(f'<{tag}>')
        pass  # end handle_starttag

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        # if not limit reached collect closing tag
        if not self.__limit_reached:
            self.__tags.append(f'</{tag}>')
            # remove closing tag from stack if it matches last tag
            if tag == self.__peek_tag(): self.__pop_tag()
        pass  # end handle_endtag

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if not self.__limit_reached:
            data = data.strip()
            # append data : if data found and tag is not in skip list
            if data and (self.__peek_tag() not in _SKIP_TAGS):
                data_len = len(data)
                if self.__parse_len + data_len < self.max_len:
                    self.__tags.append(data)
                    self.__parse_len += data_len
                else:
                    self.__limit_reached = True
    

def __trim_tags(html_string: str, max_length: int) -> str:
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    if len(html_string) < max_length:
        logger.debug(_NO_TRIMMING)
        # return _NO_TRIMMING + html_string
        return html_string
    else:
        trim_parser = TrimParser(max_length)
        trim_parser.feed(html_string)
        trimmed_html = trim_parser.html_text().strip()
        if trimmed_html:
            logger.debug('html trimmed successfully.')
            return _WARNING_HTM + trimmed_html + _TRIMMED_HTM
        else:
            logger.debug('trim html failed, trimming text')
            return _WARNING_TXT + html_string.strip()[0:max_length] + _TRIMMED_TXT
        
    

def __remove_skip_tags(html_string):
    for skip_tag in _SKIP_TAGS:
        skip_string = fr'<{skip_tag}.*?>.*?</{skip_tag}>'
        script_pattern = re.compile(skip_string, re.DOTALL)
        html_string = script_pattern.sub('', html_string)
    return html_string

#function to remove JavaScripts and CSS
def trim_parse_html(html_string: str, max_length: int = 7000) -> str:
    if len(html_string) < max_length:
        return html_string
    else:
        html_string = __remove_skip_tags(html_string)
        # if html_string in range after removiing skip tags return it
        if len(html_string) < max_length:
            return html_string
        #else remove extra tags using trim_tags
        else:
            return __trim_tags(html_string, max_length)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    html_text = """<html>

    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        let i = 10;
        if (i < 5) {
        // some code
        }
        //]]>
        </script>

        <style>
            div {
            height: 100px;
            width: 500px;
            background-color: powderblue;
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
    <h2>An Unordered HTML List</h2>
        <script>
            console.log('aaaaaa')
        </script>
        <style>
            div {
            height: 100px;
            width: 500px;
            background-color: powderblue;
            }
        </style>

    <ul>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>  
    <h2>An Ordered HTML List</h2>
        <script>
            console.log('bbbbb')
        </script>
    <ol>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
    </ol> 
    </body>
    </html>"""

    out_html = trim_parse_html(html_text)
    print(html_text)
    print("Trimmed HTML")
    print(out_html)

